# ** SuiteScript 2.0 ** Error while creating search object in client script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

searchResultSet.columns.length --> undefined....

what is missing in this code ?

---

function pageInit(scriptContext) {

```
    try{  
    var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
    var searchObj = search.load({
       id:'customsearchvc_bt_duplicate_vendor_list'
    });

    var searchResultSet=searchObj.run();
    var noOfDupVendors = searchResultSet.length;  

    log.debug({details: "there are "+searchResultSet.columns.length+" duplicate vendors"});

    currentRecord.setText({
        fieldId: 'custrecordvc_merge_vendor_total_unique_v',
        text: noOfDupVendors
    });

    }catch(e){
        log.error("error at getinputdata stage","error detail is :"+e.message);
    }
```

Comment: Despite my answer, a really good way to accomplish the goal of the code you shared is actually with a dynamic field with results derived from a summary search. No SuiteScript required.  Checkout the Netsuite Help for: `Creating Custom Fields with Values Derived from Summary Search Results` for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `length` property on the searchResultSet object.  The set doesn't *actually* contain the results(i know, it's weird)  You need to iterate through the results to total them.  In your case, you may be able to get away with a sloppy "it'll always be less than 1000" solution:

```
var searchResults = searchResultSet.getResults({
    start: 0, 
    end: 1000
});

var noOfDupVendors = searchResults.length
```

A solution for *infinite* results could look something like this: (untested):

```
var searchResults;
var noOfDupVendors = 0;

do{
    searchResults = searchResultSet.getResults({
        start: noOfDupVendors,
        end: noOfDupVendors+1000
    });
    noOfDupVendors += searchResults.length
}while(searchResults.length == 1000);
```

Another (also untested) compact way, if you can count on 4000 or fewer results would be:

```
var noOfDupVendors = 0;

searchResultSet.each(function(result){noOfDupVendors++; return true;})
```

Comment: Thank you thank you :) .. This worked and yes, I see your point :)